# Testing a function error ORA-00923

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create an `FUNCTION` that gets the location of the parameter entered which is id entered when i test the function it doesn't work it giving the error `ORA-00923`

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_LOCATION (l_con_id in NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 
  AS 
    LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);
  BEGIN
    SELECT LOCATION 
      INTO LOCATION 
      FROM LDS_CONSULTANT 
      WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;

    RETURN LOCATION;
  END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion.

First, a simple test case:

```
SQL> create table lds_consultant
  2  (consultant_id number,
  3   location      varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into lds_consultant
  2    select 1, 'New York' from dual union
  3    select 2, 'London'   from dual;

2 rows created.
```

A function:

- name parameter so that its name clearly differs from column name. Let it *inherit* column datatype
- the same goes for the return value. Preceding its name with, for example, "L_" shows that it is a local variable
- using the MAX function in SELECT statement is a simple way of avoiding TOO_MANY_ROWS or NO_DATA_FOUND errors. I'd, though, suggest you properly handle those if necessary

---

```
SQL> create or replace function get_location
  2    (par_consultant_id in lds_consultant.consultant_id%type)
  3  return lds_consultant.location%type
  4  is
  5    l_location lds_consultant.location%type;
  6  begin
  7    select max(l.location)
  8      into l_location
  9      from lds_consultant l
 10      where l.consultant_id = par_consultant_id;
 11    return l_location;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Finally, the way you call it: the *standard* way by *selecting ... from dual*:

```
SQL> select get_location(2)  result_1,
  2         get_location(-1) result_2
  3  from dual;

RESULT_1                       RESULT_2
------------------------------ ------------------------------
London

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

As Apex uses PL/SQL, you'd have to declare a local variable and put the result of that function into it. Something like this:

```
declare
  l_result lds_consultant.location%type;
begin
  l_result := get_location(:P1_CONSULTANT_ID);
end;
```

Or, if it were a report, you'd include it into the SELECT statement as

```
select l.consultant_id, 
       l.consultant_name,
       get_location(l.consultant_id) location
from lds_consultant l
order by l.consultant_name;
```

By the way, *selecting from dual* works anywhere in Oracle (Apex included).

Comment: how would i implement that to apex application ? as i am trying to test within an application

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my message and added some more examples; have a look.

Comment: thank you!! hello again ive implemented the code and assigned it to a process and a button but theirs no action could you possible tell me were im going wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Could you describe it? (It is almost midnight here and I'm going to sleep, but will see your reply tomorrow).

Comment: I am trying to input the id in to a form then the return be the location but when i try to do it in the application the buttons dont work

Comment: Aha. Try to create a "Set value" dynamic action on the ID item.

Comment: ive tried that could you possibly send me a application file with it implemented as an example so i could understand

Comment: Nope. But, if you create an example on apex.oracle.com and provide credentials, someone might have a look at what you did and, hopefully, fix it.

Comment: if i provide you credentials could you have a look ?